# Point-to-point Communication of Arduinos with RFM LoRa Shield

Tags: arduino-uno

In [this tutorial](https://cytrontechnologies.github.io/RFM-LoRa-Shield-Examples/Arduino-Sketches-Overview/), it sends a string from a node to the other node. But if I want to send an integer instead of a string, how should I change the code?

```
Serial.println("Sending to rf95_server");
// Send a message to rf95_server

String radiopacket = "Hello World #";
radiopacket += String(packetnum++);
radiopacket += " from ";
radiopacket += node_id;

Serial.print("Sending "); Serial.println(radiopacket); delay(10);
rf95.send((uint8_t*)radiopacket.c_str(), radiopacket.length()+1);

Serial.println("Waiting for packet to complete..."); delay(10);
rf95.waitPacketSent();
```

Comment: You can either convert it to text (sprintf) or send it as bytes. However you like. How do you *want* to send it?

Comment: i want to send the data generated from the ultrasonic sensor, how can i send the data as byte? sorry i'm new in programming

Comment: I can tell...  Data is just data - whether it's a string or a number. It's just data.  An `int` is just two bytes. You can send it by casting it as bytes (as you already do with the existing code) with a size of 2 bytes. Just remember to cast it using the address of the integer, not the value of the integer.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to just cast the integer into an array of 2 bytes and send that.  Assuming `int temperature`:

```
rf95.send((uint8_t *)&temperature, 2);
```

To make it more portable you can use the size of an integer instead of 2:

```
rf95.send((uint8_t *)&temperature, sizeof(int));
```

Reading back, you just cast the buffer you have received as an integer, or combine the data manually (which may be safer since the buffer may be misaligned on a more powerful system than an 8 bit Arduino):

```
int temperature = buf[0] | (buf[1] << 8);
```

(Assuming it was sent from a *little-endian* 8-bit system).

If you want to send the number as plain text, so it can be easily read by a human, you want to print it to a string:

```
char temp[6];
sprintf(temp, "%d", temperature);
rf95.send((uint8_t *)temp, strlen(temp));
```

Comment: thanks for the help, but i received weird symbol on the server side 
. do i need to change anything on the server side so that i can get a proper integer?

Comment: Yes. I told you what to change.

Comment: Note that the binary methods are only "portable" when the machines on both ends use the same variable size and byte order, as may indeed be the case here.  Otherwise the packing and unpacking will need to be done explicitly, something specified in many network protocols for example.  This would work between two ATmega Arduinos, or two Due Arduinos, but not between a mixed collection without explicit handling.

Answer (score 0):

Just cast the integer to a String before sending and convert the String back to an int when you received. May not be memory friendly considering you are using Strings, but its very easy.

```
int a = 10;
String s = String(a);
```

You can then send the String as you would a normal string. Then on the receiving end you cast back to an int.

Assuming you received a String s.

```
int b = s.toInt();
```